# Install iOS 4.2 on an iPad for testing

Tags: ipad, ios, ios-4.2

How do I install iOS 4.2 Beta on my iPad device to test my apps against?

I have installed the Xcode 4.2 development suit and use Monotouch to test in the emulator on 4.2, but can't figure out how to get 4.2 on my physical iPad.

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the iOS 4.2 image for iPad on your machine. Double click to mount it in Finder. Open iTunes, click on your iPad device, and then Option+click on the Update button. this will open a dialog to browse for the local iOS image.

Answer (score 1):

Officially you need be an iPhone Developer: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Will find the info there.

Or you can go the unsafe route and download the firmware from a site and install, but I dont recommend that.